# SignalR Core contract and error with .NET Core : is there any way to make contract and throw error when SignalR supply wrong parameter and catch?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm pretty confused with SignalR typescript from Microsoft. When I send wrong method, or right method with wrong parameter number or less supplied parameter, I don't get any error, and I need to debug it via VS Code debug, which takes time. Sometimes I got twisted between parameter when the code on .NET Core changed.

Is there anyway to help simplify and make it more stricter, like grpc/protobuf? So It's simpler to debug, when I do something wrong? Or is there anyway to have contract on top of SignalR?

I also tried using `catch` on the promise, but when send wrong parameters or random method or wrong parameters, it won't get any error.

For example:

```js
TestError()
{
    this.connection.send("aaaa", "Aaa").catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
}
```

the hubs example

```cs
using ChatSignalR.Helper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace ChatSignalR.Hubs;

public class ChatHubs : Hub
{
    private ListGroup _groups;

    public ChatHubs(ListGroup group)
    {
        _groups = group;
    }

    public async Task JoinGroup(string groupName, string username) 
    {
        _groups.AddGroup(groupName);
        _groups.AddUserToGroup(username, groupName);

        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("sendGroup", Context.ConnectionId, $"{Context.ConnectionId} joinded the group!");
        await SendListGroups();
        return;
    }

    public async Task LeaveGroup(string groupName, string username)
    {
        await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        _groups.RemoveUserFromGroup(username, groupName);
        var count = _groups.GetNumberOfUserInGroup(groupName);
        await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("sendGroup", Context.ConnectionId, $"{Context.ConnectionId} has left the group {groupName}.");

        if (count <= 0)
        {
            _groups.RemoveGroup(groupName);
            await SendListGroups();
        }
    }

    public async Task SendChatGroup(string groupName, string msg)
    {
        await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("sendGroup", Context.ConnectionId, $"{Context.ConnectionId}:{msg}");
    }

    public async Task SendListGroups()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("listGroups", _groups.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Beware, that what I mean is, I tried random method, but it won't throw an error..., what I need is when I put random or wrong method or even parameter, I need it to throw error...**

It won't even throw an error.

EDIT: Some asking for the code, so I provide on https://gitlab.com/benlimanto-salt/chat-signalr

You can call any method from ChatHub, but left one parameter not send using the typescript (I'm using angular on that repository). And it won't throw an error...

Any pointers are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Post also the server code.

Comment: The sever code is only simple code @DA, it doesn't have any error whatsoever, only won't be invoked, and it will won't be fired if it's not with right parameter... https://gitlab.com/benlimanto-salt/chat-signalr you can see that code..

Comment: Did u follow these recommendations? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio for example UseCors should be called before MapHub... and so on....

Comment: @DA Near, but I'm using typrscript... and it's based on the best practice... I tried the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#error-handling-and-logging no avail

Comment: Use Invoke instead of Send. `connection.invoke("aaaa", "Aaa").catch((e) => {});`

Comment: I try to use `catch()` in java script and it can report error message successfully, but it seems don't work in type script.